# Unable to make it working a JSF test project

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to create a test project for `JSF` (`Primefaces`), but it does not work. The test view does not call the managed bean.

This is the managed bean:

```java
package it.myPrimefacesTest.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld", eager=true)
public class HelloWorld implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7184399511928573344L;
    
   @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
   public String getMessage() {
      return "Hello World!";
   }
}
```

This is `test.xhtml`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   contentType="text/html"
>
   
<html>
<h:head></h:head>
    
<body>
    ciao!
      
    <h:inputText></h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.getMessage()}"></h:outputText>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyPrimefacesTest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyPrimefacesTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyPrimefacesTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyPrimefacesTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <context-param> 
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>test.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

`faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1"
>

</faces-config>
```

`<h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.getMessage()}"></h:outputText>` in `test.xhtml` does not work.

I'm using:

- `Java` 7
- `Eclipse`
- `JBoss` 7.1.1

This is because my project was created in this way, and I want to be 1:1.

This is the project: https://ufile.io/ihd8j37g . You have to click on Free Download and then on Slow Speed.

Comment: Why not just use PrimeFaces Test and just change the pom.xml to 3.4.1 ???  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: As I said, I want to replicate the original program 1:1. Unluckily I'm not the author of the program.

Comment: Which java version are you using to run this project? Do you use the default standalone configuration or do you do some significant changes to it? Do you use standard jsf and jsf-impl jar from jBoss or do you override them with specific ones?

Comment: @WoAiNii I'm using Java 7 standard  as the original working project. I'm using a standard JBoss installation.

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: @MarcoSulla yes now it's working, for some reason it didn't worked first time.

Comment: As you can see in the ear, or in the deployed files, there's no source file(.class), so you need to check how you pack your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks to [WoAiNii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732966/1763602) for suggesting me in the right direction. This is what I have done in `Project -> Properties`:

1. `Java Build path -> Source -> Default output folder`: set to `MyPrimefacesTest/build/classes`
2. `Deployment Assembly` -> `Add` -> `Folder` -> `src`, then I set the Deploy path to `WEB-INF/classes`
3. reboot the PC (for superstition...)
4. go to the JBoss `standalone` folder, deleted the subfolders `data`, `log` and `tmp` and empty the `deployments` folder
5. start Eclipse
6. Clean the project and the EAR project
7. Go to Servers. If you servers has other EARs than this one, remove them. Make sure to clear the other servers before start this one.
8. clear the server
9. start the server
10. pray :D

Answer (score 2):

If you try to examine your deployed ear, you'll see that inside `MyPrimefacesTest.war` there's only PF jar, `faces-config.xml` and `web.xml`, no `.class` file.
Same thing if you export your project into an ear file.
Since the compiled code isn't deployed it's impossible to run it at runtime.
If you export your MyPrimefacesTest output folder, in your war, you'll see the problem resolved.
To do it you can try replacing

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
```

with

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes" path="src"/>
```

in `.classpath` file of `MyPrimefacesTest`.

Depending on your need you can choose between many ways to obtain this goal:

- Modify your classpath
- Modify Manifest
- If you use maven you can modify pom.xml according to your need, same thing for gradle or if you use ant script

Remember to clean your server, before deploying a new ear (with lower jBoss version it's usefull to clean also deployment dir).

Comment: Well, this is what I have done in project -> properties: `1.` Java build path -> source -> default output folder -> setted to MyPrimefacesTest/build/classes `2.` Deployment assembly -> add -> folder -> src -> edited deploy path to WEB-INF/classes. The .class files now are deployed but the code still NOT work.

Comment: I don't know, now it works. Nothing changed. Oh well... I'll write my answer, if you integrate my steps I'll accept yours :)

Comment: Nothing changed from the starting point or from the classpath change? (I feel stupid to write to you en english ^^)

Comment: No, I downloaded the zip and I confronted them with WinMerge :D

Comment: The actual archive works fine, the main problem was the content of the deployed ear.

Comment: Yes, but was not sufficient to add the output folder